# EGit Compare shows all lines as changed

Tags: egit

Just installed Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) which comes with EGit (which I updated to EGit 3.2.201312181205-r), and [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/).  I cloned a repository in the Git for Windows Bash shell under an existing Eclipse workspace, and then in Eclipse imported it as a project.  However, if I right click a file that I haven't changed and select Compare With > HEAD Revision, it shows all lines as different.

In the Git for Windows bash shell, git diff on the file shows nothing. Running `od -c` on the file in Git bash shows it has Windows-style line endings.

When I go into Eclipse preferences for Compare/Patch and say to ignore whitespace, it shows no differences.  But I'd like to understand why that is necessary.

What is really being compared here?

Comment: In the git configuration, what value does `core.autocrlf` have (use `git config core.autocrlf`)?

Comment: Could you find out what kind of line endings the file has in the Git repository? E.g. do `git show HEAD:path/to/file > file.txt` and look at the line endings. I suspect EGit may not be converting the line endings from LF to CRLF for the HEAD side of the comparison.

Comment: The show version of the file has LF only.

Answer (score 8):

This is a know bug in Egit. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372

Even in Egit 3.4 (planned for June 2014) it won't be fixed. Robin Stocker gave this suggestion in the duplicate of the above bug:

> Until this is implemented, I recommend this setup:
>
> 1. For each Eclipse project, go to Properties > Resource and change "New text file line delimiter" to Other: Unix. Commit the resulting
>      .settings/org.eclipse.core.runtime.prefs files.
> 2. Don't configure any .gitattributes or "core.autocrlf" for Git. This means that files will have the same line endings in the working
>      directory as in the repository. Git and EGit will not convert any file
>      contents.
>
> With 1., all new files that are created in Eclipse will have correct
>   (LF) line endings, even when created by a user on Windows.
>
> For files that are already in your repository with CRLF, you can fix
>   them and commit the result. I recommend using dos2unix or fromdos on
>   the command line.

However it's been reported that Egit ignores these settings when importing a project. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421364

So it looks like all developers need to check the line endings themselves. But least you don't need any other tools to fix this. Under the **File** menu in Eclipse there's a: "Convert Line Delimiters To". Also note there are line ending settings for both individual  projects and in the workspace settings.

For projects: right-click -> properities -> Resource

For Workspace: Window -> preferences -> General -> Workspace